# No redirects? Load content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reload

Just a quick question. Why should/shouldn't I create a website that loads it's content using javascript only? Users can still link special content on the website because I'm using "#" tags in the URL to keep track of variables/pages.

Answer (score 1):

*It is inaccessible*. If the user agent doesn't support JavaScript, then no content will load. (Search engine indexing bots have *very* limited to no JS support).

*It is not robust*. A tiny error or network failure when loading the JS will [give you an outage](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2011/02/07/gawker-outage-causing-twitter-stir/).

*It is inefficient*. Loading a page requires that the homepage be loaded and then the content be replaced by another page. [Twitter stopped doing this](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-twittercom) because it was a horrible experience for users.

---

The [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) lets us have real URLs without depending on client side trickery. You get the benefits of the approach described in the question while mitigating most of the drawbacks.

Alice can go to `/foo/`, the server can build `/foo/` and the page can load quickly. She can then click a link to `/bar/` and you can use `pushState` and `XMLHttpRequest` to replace the URL and the part of the page that would change.

Alice sends a link to Bob. Bob goes to `/bar/` and the server can build it and the page can load quickly. etc.